# An elegant way to clear this.setState tasks when unmounting, w/o this.mounted pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am already using an AbortController signal to cancel fetching on unmounting, but is there an elegant way to prevent memory leaks when trying to setState on an unmounted component, without setting `this.mounted = true` on `componentDidMount`, and `false` on `componentWillUnmount`, combining with `this.mounted && ...` conditionals?

In the following example It might only be 2 occasions which isn't a big deal, but just wondering if there is a better way/pattern

```
import React from 'react';
import {fetchPopularRepos} from '../utils/api';

export default class Popular extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const AbortController = window.AbortController;
        this.controller = new AbortController();
        this.signal = this.controller.signal;
        this.state = {
            selectedLanguage: 'All',
            repos: new Map(),
            error: null
        };
        this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() { this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage); }

    componentWillUnmount() { this.controller.abort(); }

    async updateLanguage(selectedLanguage) {
        this.setState({selectedLanguage, error: null});
        if (this.state.repos.has(selectedLanguage))
            return;
        try {
            const data = await fetchPopularRepos(selectedLanguage, this.signal);
            this.setState(({repos})=> ({
                repos: repos.set(selectedLanguage, data)
            }));
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn('Error fetching repos ...', err);
            this.setState({error: err.message});
        }
    }

    // rest of code ...
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't try it but how about `componentWillUnmount() { this.setState = () => {} }` ?

Comment: @rksh1997 Yes, this seems to work in my case.
However I just noticed while writing this comment that the mem leak error I receive happens because the fetch abort throws an error, which triggers `this.setState({error: err.message});`, so basically I only need to set one check with `this.mounted && this.setState({error: err.message});`
Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Overwriting `setState` function is an opposite thing to the _elegant_ word.